# How to retrieve text data from multiple HTML tags?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, web-scraping, xpath, beautifulsoup

I have the following HTML snippet output stored in variable named `content` of type `bs4.element.Tag`.

```html
<li class="item">
                                            Alpha-tocopherol
                                            <em>see</em>
<a href="https://medlineplus.gov/vitamine.html">Vitamin E</a>
</li>
```

`str(content)` output:

```py
'<li class="item">\n                                            Alpha-tocopherol\n                                            <em>see</em>\n<a href="https://medlineplus.gov/vitamine.html">Vitamin E</a>\n</li>'
```

I would like to use Python to get as output: `['Alpha-tocopherol', 'Vitamin E']`.
I tried the following but it is wrong:

```py
regex = re.compile('(\w+\s+)\n')
regex.sub('', content.text).split()
```

Comment: [The obligatory post about the futility of trying to parse X/HTML with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/62576) Use a DOM parser instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the first tag by using the [`.contents`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) method and then use the [`.find_next()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) method to search for an `a` tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<li class="item">
Alpha-tocopherol
<em>see</em>
<a href="https://medlineplus.gov/vitamine.html">Vitamin E</a>
</li>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.find_all("li", class_="item"):
    print([tag.contents[0].strip(), tag.find_next("a").text])
```

Output:

```
['Alpha-tocopherol', 'Vitamin E']
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of these will produce the list you want. With the first one though, it depends on how the html element is parsed. If there's page breaks \n, you'll have to do some extra parsing.

```
html = '''<li class="item">Alpha-tocopherol<em>see</em><a href="https://medlineplus.gov/vitamine.html">Vitamin E</a></li>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

soup.text.split('see') # option 1, get all text and parse accordingly from soup object

soup.find('li', class_='item').text.split('see') # option 2, get text from li element (seems like it'd be less efficient to do this)
```

Output

```
['Alpha-tocopherol, 'Vitamin E']
```